# Why is my element giving me 'undefined' in this jquery .each() function...?

Tags: jquery

I'm having some problems with this jQuery....I'm new to it.  It looks like it's the same as the example I'm taking it from...

```
$.getJSON('<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/MyService.aspx") %>',
    function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, elem) {
            alert(elem.Name);
        });
    }
);
```

elem.Name always says 'undefined'!  I'm getting the following data returned from my service...

```
{"ID":1,"Name":"David Bowie"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting mixed up in how `.each` works.

This by itself would work:

```
$.getJSON('<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/MyService.aspx") %>',
    function(data) {
        alert(data.Name);
    }
);
```

`data` in your JSON callback is your JSON data.

The `.each` function will iterate through all the elements in that object and call your function once for each element. So your function would get called twice — once with `index` being `ID` and once with `index` being `Name`. That doesn't seem at all appropriate given the object you have.

Comment: Thanks, mate...I just realised my service was returning 1 object whilst the service in the example I was following was returning an array of objects.